# Batch putting a var from an upper loop in for /r

Tags: batch-file, cmd, expansion

Hi i am working on a script that basically for given folder have to see if in those folder exists jboss*\server 
So first of all i can't include jboss*/server but only jboss*, basically the wild card can only be used at the file name and not the path, is that the way it's supposed to be ?
So in order to bypass that i thught of inner loops that will solve it for me 
here is how i have started to do it

```
set jboss_dir_list=c: C:\TecsysDev\iTopiaControlPanel\trunk

for %%f in (%jboss_dir_list%) do (
    for /r %f% %%G in (jboss*) do echo %%G  
    rem for /f "usebackq delims=" %%D in (`dir /b %%f\jboss*`) do set "jboss_home_list=%jboss_home_list%%%D"

)
```

I have thought of including a third inner loop that will search for server folder, but the second one isn't working because the %f% isn't expanding, it's empty and so the search is done on the actual dos directory, i tried with %%f%% but still nothing, how do i get it expnded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my suggestion if `%jboss_dir_list%` is a variable with space-separated strings:

```
for %%f in (%jboss_dir_list%) do for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%%~f\jboss*"') do echo %%G
```

Comment: Thanks i adapted i and it works, still could you tell me why the expansion in my initial code wasn't working ?

Comment: it's because you can not use a for loop parameter itself as a for loop parameter (there are exceptions, but not with the `for /r` path parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I use findstr to mach "jboss.*\server" using reqex

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /A:D /B /S "C:\TecsysDev\iTopiaControlPanel\trunk\"') do (
    echo %%a|findstr "jboss.*\server">nul
    if !errorlevel!==0 echo %%a

        rem Add your code here.
)
```